# Running a Powershell script on another server from a PHP script?

Tags: php, powershell

Our company's system has two servers, one that handles web-side scripts, and another that contains all our Active Directory information. Let's call them "webServer" and "adServer".

I have a Powershell (V5) script on adServer that returns an AD account's password expiration date. I'm writing a PHP script on webServer where a user can input a username, then have that account's password expiration date printed to them. Thus, I need to call the Powershell script from this PHP script.

I know you use shell_exec() to run Powershell scripts in PHP, but how would I run a script on a different server? Assuming C:\pwdDate.ps1 is the file path on adServer, this is all I have right now:

```
$pwdExpDate = shell_exec('powershell -File C:\pwdDate.ps1 -Username $username');

echo $pwdExpDate
```

Comment: `this is all I have right now` - and it won't run, because you can't use $username inside a single quote string. Any reason you aren't using LDAP from PHP to AD? There's a lot of examples of that around on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you set up a [web ...] service on the second computer, which your PHP application can *request* to run the PowerShell script (or to do anything else that needs doing).

This keeps *you* firmly in control of what's going on ... an especially important consideration when the target server is doing "juicy" things like managing Active Directory content. *(Intruders would love to get their hands on **that** server ...)* You don't allow *arbitrary* requests to be made.

And, it's much simpler.  The PowerShell script is being executed by a process on the same machine. *Only* that script can be run, and then, only indirectly ... "by request." You can easily take care of any concurrency issues, right there on "that" machine, within the auspices of the service-process that you create.

Microsoft IIS already provides the necessary "plumbing" to quickly set-up and manage a (e.g. SOAP ...) service.

You can use AD itself to restrict which other computer *(namely, "the web server")* is authorized to contact the other service.

**Note:** I am here using the term, "service," colloquially ... loosely ... *not* specifically in reference to a daemon-process. I'm not using Microsoft's formal meaning for the word.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not want remote powershell to be allowed on a Domain Controller, it's opening a large attack surface.

Instead you can add the [AD PS Cmdlets](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/) to the webserver and then execute the command locally.